# Can I merge two arrays by concatenating their JSON string representations?

Tags: jquery, arrays, parsing

How to use each parse the json type -

```
retrieveMessage: function()
    {
        
         $.post('ActionScripts/RetrieveMessage.php',{
   
        }, function(data) {
           
            $.each(data, function(key, reader){
                 
        alert(reader.id + reader.count); //this line does not return anything
               
            });
            
        },"json");
    }
```

data:

```
[{"id":"1","user_name":"Jenan","user_image":"ImageName","text_chat":"Hello","date":"2011-09-25 21:29:09","error":""}][{"count":"2"}]
```

I would get text -

```
id=1 count=2
```

PHP

```
$jsonresult = array();

$count = array();
$countresult = array();
$countresult["count"] = "2";
$count[] = $countresult;
while($row = mysql_fetch_array($result))
{
$thisResult = array();

$thisResult["user_auth"] = 1;
$thisResult["id"] = $row['id'];
$thisResult["user_name"] = $row['user_name'];
$thisResult["user_image"] = $row['user_image'];
$thisResult["text_chat"] = $row['text_chat'];
$thisResult["date"] = $row['date'];
$thisResult["error"] = "";

$jsonresult[] = $thisResult;
}
  echo json_encode($jsonresult) . json_encode($count);
```

Here compose two collections together. How to read the collection with id parameters and collection of the count? Is this the right solution? What solution do I choose for composing arrays?

Comment: That isn't valid JSON, you can't just have two arrays one after the next like that.  Do you have access to modify the JSON returned?

Comment: @kingjiv, it is valid JSON, but it is crap. You can have differently structured elements in each index of an array but that really indicates some really poor design from the person who implemented the server part.

Comment: @DarinDimitrov: I beg to differ.  Paste it into http://jsonlint.com/  It's just 2 arrays next to each other, not 1 object or array.

Comment: @Rocket, oh yeah, you are so right. I didn't actually notice that there were 2 arrays. Well, OP, you've got some pretty invalid JSON going on here.

Comment: I added the php part. Can you help me please?

Comment: `echo json_encode($jsonresult) . json_encode($count);`  Yeah, you can't do that...

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Instead of gluing 2 arrays together:

```
echo json_encode($jsonresult) . json_encode($count);
```

you should make one array that contains them:

```
echo json_encode(array(
   'result' => $jsonresult,
   'count' => $count
));
```

Now in your JavaScript:

```
$.post('ActionScripts/RetrieveMessage.php', {}, function(data) {
    var result = data.result;
    var count = data.count;

    $.each(result, function(k,v){
       alert(v.id+' '+count[k].count); // 1 2
    });
},"json");
```

Comment: @Jenan: `console.log` `result` and `count` to see what their actual structure is, I wasn't sure.

Answer (score 0):

try

```
 }, function(data) {
       data = eval(data);
       $.each(data, function(key, reader){
```

Comment: `eval` isn't needed here.  `,"json");` automatically parses the JSON for you, if it's valid.